# How to copy image in a folder using its name from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

i'm trying to copy the images from folder to another which have the same name that exists in a file

```
dst="t"
path = 'train' 
f = open("file_txt.txt",'r')
files = os.listdir(path)
for i in files :
    if i.endswith('.jpg'):
       j=i.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
       #print(j)
       lines = f.readlines()
       for  line in lines:
            #print(line)
            if line == j:
               #print(line)
               shutil.copy(path+'/'+line.strip(), dst)
```

j contains like

```
COCO_train2014_000000110431
COCO_train2014_000000110437
COCO_train2014_000000110439
```

line contains like

```
COCO_train2014_000000206463

COCO_train2014_000000206465

COCO_train2014_000000206467
```

but the new_folder is empty and I tried to print(line) that exists in if condition but got nothing while file_txt contains the name of the images and train is a folder contains the images itself

Comment: you could read `lines` only once - before all `for`-loop. You have to also remember that it may gives lines with `\n` at the end so you may need to use `line.strip()`. And if you have empty lines then you could skip them and run only when `if line: ...`

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you really have in variables and which part of code is executed - it is called `"print debuging"`

Comment: maybe get filenames from file, create `/full/path/to/image.jpg` and later use `os.path.exists(...)` to check if it exists, and then copy it. This way you don't need `listdir()` and you don't need nested `for`-loops.

Comment: if you would read file as `f = open(...).read().split("\n")` then you would get names without `\n'` and you could check it `if j in f:` without `for line in lines: if line == j:`

Comment: your mind problem can be that you try to copy `COCO_train2014_000000110431` without `.jpg` but you have to copy `COCO_train2014_000000110431.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mess in code but I think your problem is that you try copy `COCO_train2014_000000110431` without `.jpg` but you have to copy `COCO_train2014_000000110431.jpg`

Other problem can be: you compare `line` before you use `.strip()` so it may has `\n` at the end. So you compare `if name<enter> == name`. If you run `print(line)` then name may looks OK (because `\n` is not visible) but if you would add some chars `print(f">>>{line}<<<")` then maybe you would see that `<<<` is in new line.

---

But I would do it in different way - without `listdir()` but with `os.path.exists()`

```
import os
import shutil

src = 'train'
dst = 't'

os.makedirs(dst, exist_ok=True)  # create destination folder if not exists

filenames = open("file_txt.txt").read().split('\n')

for name in filenames:
    if name:  # to skip empty lines
        fullpath = os.path.join(src, name + '.jpg')
        if os.path.exists(fullpath):
            print('coping:', fullpath)
            shutil.copy(fullpath, dst)
        else:
            print('SKIPING:', fullpath)
```

Comment: More thanks and appreciate your help really